# How to set margins on floated DIVS

Tags: css, positioning, margins

This is a problem that for some odd reason I run into only sometimes. But how would I set a floated DIV's margin? I use negative pixels and seem to achieve the results, but when I view the page in the editor window of a CMS (ezPublisher) it looks totally disgusting and broken, but in the browser it is fine (being broken in the editor window will not fly here)

When I set an element to float:right, it kicks it way far to the left of the page, when I set the margin-left dimensions, it doesn't go anywhere.

So in short, I'm trying to ask: when I float an element to the right, what side to I set the dimensions on? margin-left? or margin-right?

Here is the page with 
http://scope-stage.scholastic.com/issues/09_01_13/

```
.articleCover {
   float:right;
   width:210px;
   margin-top:-190px; 
   margin-left:-20px;
```

}

Furthermore, I always though that you place floated elements before the element that they float next to in the markup. However, I see it either way sometimes. Thanks for the help, and I hope I was clear on my issue.

Comment: What is `.articleCover` on that site?

Comment: Why position with negative margins? Why not just use relative placement?

Comment: I tried to do the relative placement but it utterly looked broken. Again, positioning is my weakest point in CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I hit the enter button too soon, .articleCover is the div that holds the magazine cover images next to each article description.

Comment: Maybe you should change its position in the markup instead.

Comment: you mean put the float element first? That's how I learned.

Comment: Yea, in a situation like this, I would just rearrange the HTML, which will then limit the redundancies in the CSS.

Comment: Does your page look broken in a regular browser or just when using the CMS ezPublisher?

Comment: well, when I use the negatives it looks fine in regular browser, but there are two pages of edit in the ezPublisher (which I have to use), one says "edit" then you click it and it is fine, however when I click the second edit page (dont know why there are two) it looks might broken

Comment: How many people are using your editor to view the webpage?  If the answer is absolutely zero, this seems to be a non-issue.

Comment: I know it shouldn't be, but I'm not sure. I'm betting that there will be an instance that SOMEONE will want to use it and of course they'll have a heart attack and I'll get hung. Negatives are the only thing moving these elements around. I was tossed into this project with no familiarity of the global style sheet (which I'm trying to look at to work around and within)...but I'm just wondering why is that negatives is the only thing that moves these elements.

Comment: If browsers display it properly, then the editor is broken.

Comment: That's what I'm going with. But the other pages they have look fine in the editor, but like I said I don't know their global style all the way, for bran new pages I use a mockup based on the style guide and code the way I know how (which admittedly, is shaky when it comes to positioning)